# Sinatra LoadError

Tags: ruby, path, sinatra, sinatra-assetpack

While working on a Sinatra App, I came about a peculiar problem, hopefully which someone could help me out with.
I'm running ruby 1.9.3 and when I run my app using `ruby myapp.rb` It runs on the localhost with an error.
However when I tried `sudo ruby myapp.rb` It gives me an error that Sinatra could not be loaded and when it shows me the library from which it pulls sinatra, it is /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1

I think thats where my problem is, but I don't know how to change this path. Do I do it in my app, or terminal to change the path for ruby, any help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're using RVM for 1.9.3, you can just do

```
rvmsudo ruby myapp.rb
```

If you've set up 1.9.3 some other way, figure out the location of your 1.9.3 binary by doing:

```
$ which ruby
/whatever/path/ruby-1.9.3-p125/bin/ruby
$ sudo /whatever/path/ruby-1.9.3-p125/bin/ruby myapp.rb
```

You could also just install Sinatra and any other gems needed for your system Ruby:

```
sudo gem install sinatra
```

Comment: Perfect. I was using rvm so `rvmsudo ruby myapp.rb` worked perfectly.
Thank you so much!